# How to fetch only the values from an object ignoring the null values in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object `saResponse` which looks as below:

```
0: {severity: "Low", assignee: null, notesType: "Type1", notes: "Notes1", createdAt: "2020-07-29"}
length: 1
```

I want to convert this Object into String such that only values are displayed separted by `::` and ignoring `null` values.

### Desired Output

```
Low::Type1::Details1::2020-07-29
```

I have added below code but it is not giving desired output

```
 const saValue = Object.values(saResponse).map
                (el => Object.entries(el).filter(([key, value]) => value !== null).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({
                    ...acc,
                    [key]: value
                }), {}));
const saStringValue = JSON.stringify(saValue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work and make it easier.

```js
const saResponse = {
    0: {severity: "Low", assignee: null, notesType: "Type1", notes: "Notes1", createdAt: "2020-07-29"},
    1: {severity: "High", assignee: "meallhour", notesType: null, notes: "Notes1", createdAt: "2021-07-29"},
};

const saValue = Object.values(saResponse)
    .map((row) => Object
        .values(row)
        .filter(val => val)
        .join('::')
).join(',');

console.log(saValue);
```

Comment: Getting an error - `TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'SAInterface'.`

Comment: Click on `Run code snippet` and see the console log output. If you're getting that error it means your `saResponds` "array object" is not an array at all. You'll have to give us the real shape before we can help you. Also this is a typescript error. You asked a Javascript question. You have to do your own types here

Comment: The answer with `.values(saResponse[0])` is working fine. `saResponse` is an object and i have updated my question accordingly. Now, in case of multiple values i want them to be separated with `, `  Please let me know the updated answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

From what I could deduce from your post and comments, I think the structure for the variable `saResponse` is this:

[image: saResponse]

You have an array with only a single item in it as the `length` property's value is `1`.
The item which is in it is an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Now, in your case, you only have a single item but I'm posting answers for both scenarios where you've only one item and in the second one multiple items in the array. Please make suitable changes to the code-snippet below according to your needs.

```
let saResponse = [
    { severity: "Low", assignee: null, notesType: "Type1", notes: "Notes1", createdAt: "2020-07-29" },
    { severity: "High", assignee: 'john', notesType: null, notes: "Notes1", createdAt: "2020-06-27" }
];

// For array with only one element
let result = Object.values(saResponse[0]).filter(el => el !== null).join('::');

// For array with multiple elements
let result2 = saResponse.map(obj => Object.values(obj).filter(el => el !== null).join('::'))
```

Also, I've tested the value only against `null` as you specifically mentioned you didn't want `null` values. However, I'm not sure if you have a good idea about falsy values because among many falsy values in javascript, `null` is one of them. Other falsy values are `undefined`, `0`, `""(empty string)`, `false` etc. Please read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) if you want more information on this.

If you don't want any falsy values then you could simply replace `.filter(el => el !== null)` with `.filter(el => el)`.

Comment: I am getting `[object Object]` when trying to do `console.log(result)`

Comment: For the answer that I posted, I'm getting the result "Low::Type1::Notes1::2020-07-29" which looks correct to me. Please note, in my code-snippet, "saResponse" is an object and not an array. And I addressed my confusion in the answer regarding this.

Comment: When i check details for `saResponse`, I see below   `Array(1)
0: {severity: "Low", assignee: null, notesType: "Type1", notes: "Notes1", createdAt: "2020-07-29"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)`

Comment: I am getting an error - `Getting an error - TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'SAInterface'.`

Comment: This is working fine - `const saValue = Object.values(saResponse[0]).filter(val => val)
.join('::');`     But, how to address multiple elements using above?

Comment: I've added solution for multiple elements in my answer, please check once.

Comment: I believe `saResponse` is of type `SAInterface` and for multiple elements i am getting an error - `TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'SAInterface'.`

Comment: Please add either a screenshot or add the whole code-snippets to the post because I can only help you in a very limited way and that I've already done by posting and explaining my code.

Comment: If SAInterface is a class or an interface(if you're using typescript), then the method map won't be available on it. "map" method is only present on arrays and for arrays you could see the implementation in my answer.

Comment: the answer from Dominik is working. thanks for all your help!!

Answer (score 1):

```
// i have tried this and it work, but i cannot get where you get `Details 1` string?
const object1 = {severity: "Low", assignee: null, notesType: "Type1", notes: "Notes1", 
createdAt: "2020-07-29"};

const arr = Object.values(object1);
const filtered = arr.filter( el=>( 
   el != null)
);

console.log(filtered.join('::'))
```